# Scrape multiple pages of DuckDuckGo's HTML

Tags: php, web-scraping, duckduckgo

I've created a simple PHP script to scrape DuckDuckGo's html.duckduckgo.com. I'm looking to scrape more than the first page of results. The library I am using only supports GET requests and I can't seem to find the GET param that will show a new page of results.

Pressing the "next" button sends a POST request to DDG, and I've tried adding params from the POST request to the GET request with no luck.

[image: dev tools]

Any idea how I could find the GET param to see the next page of results? Does such a thing even exist?

This is my current code, I'm using [DiDOM](https://github.com/imangazaliev/didom).

```php
<?php

require "../vendor/autoload.php";

use DiDom\Document;

$document = new Document('https://html.duckduckgo.com/html/?q=test', true);

$posts = $document->find('.result__url');

$links = [];

foreach($posts as $post) {
    array_push($links, trim($post->text()));
}

$api = json_encode($links);
file_put_contents("links.json", $api);
```

Comment: Is there code to go with this? Should it have a php tag?

Comment: Its not much of a PHP question, its more of how I would go about scraping multiple pages of DDG

Comment: Scraping how? Are you not using php to perform this scraping? Labelling with the intended language / framework will better draw the attention of the relevant experts.

Comment: Fair, I edited my post.

Comment: you can use `cURL` for fetching data pass it to  `DiDom`